# Java: вывести слова из текста в алфавитном порядке

Tags: java

Есть массив со словами, как вывести слова в массиве по алфавиту и посчитать сколько одинаковых слов, например:

```
String[] words = {"a", "a", "at", "but", "down", "he", "wolf", "wolf"};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли вывести массив через циклы или надо писать кучу `if`? У меня получилось так:

```
private void sortWords() {
    String[] words = {"a", "a", "at", "but", "down", "he", "wolf", "wolf"};
    char q;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (char j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; j++) {
            q = words[i].charAt(0);
            if (q == j) {
                System.out.println(j + ": " + words[i] + " - " + (i + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с использованием `TreeMap` и `stream api`:

```
String[] words = {"a", "a", "at", "but", "down", "he", "wolf", "wolf"};

TreeMap<String, Integer> wordsQuantity = new TreeMap<>();

Arrays.stream(words).forEach(word -> {
    int quantity = wordsQuantity.getOrDefault(word, 0);
    wordsQuantity.put(word, quantity + 1);
});

System.out.println(wordsQuantity); // {a=2, at=1, but=1, down=1, he=1, wolf=2}
```

В данном случае порядок слов определяется компаратором по умолчанию `natural ordering`, т.е. по алфавиту, а чтоб совсем как в задаче было, можно еще один `stream` добавить:

```
wordsQuantity.forEach((word, quantity) ->
            System.out.println(word.charAt(0) + ": " + word + " - " + quantity));

// a: a - 2
// a: at - 1
// b: but - 1
// d: down - 1
// h: he - 1
// w: wolf - 2
```

---

**UPD:** Немного допилил (спасибо [@And](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209349)) - можно одним `stream` обойтись, и работает быстрее:

```
String[] words = {"a", "a", "at", "but", "down", "he", "wolf", "wolf"};

Arrays.stream(words)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
    .forEach((word, quantity) ->
        System.out.println(word.charAt(0) + ": " + word + " - " + quantity));

// a: a - 2
// a: at - 1
// b: but - 1
// d: down - 1
// h: he - 1
// w: wolf - 2
```

Comment: да, стримы и коллекции, наверное, стоят потраченного времени. А то я знал же, что мне подойдёт какая-то штука, которая логично объединит строку и число, но я ее не особо помнил, потому не стал применять.

Comment: Быстрее? В каком месте? С использованием `TreeMap` - это только медленее. Это вам так кажется, что написав 2 строчки, будет быстрее.  =) Загляните внутрь `TreeMap` и поймете, о чем я =) Мой код проигрывал, только из за `asList`. Сортировка через `Map` работает быстрее. И чем больше итераций, тем медленнее становится `TreeMap` из-за всяких группировок, блокировок и сортировок, а вы сверху еще до кучи группировку добавили.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] words = {"a", "a", "at", "but", "down", "he", "wolf", "wolf"};
Arrays.stream(words)
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()))
.entrySet()
.stream()
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
.forEachOrdered(action -> {
    String name = action.getKey();
    System.out.println(name.charAt(0) + ": " + name + " - " + action.getValue());
});
```

Вывод:

```
a: a - 2
a: at - 1
b: but - 1
d: down - 1
h: he - 1
w: wolf - 2
```